# Enable developer options on UMX android phone model number U673C

Tags: android, android-settings

Every set of instructions I pull up says I need to tap build number, but there is no build number on this menu. [image]
What do I hit instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to tap "software version" a few times. You'll get a notification that says "you're on your way to being a developer in 3  taps", or something like that. 
Yeesh this was needlessly frustrating there should be a central source for the varying ways to access developer options on these different phones.